# Will an android device receive ip multicasts from a broadcasting device which is connected to a different SSID

Tags: android, ip, wifi, multicast

I have a 1 sender and 1 receiver Android device. What I notice with my Android receiver device is that it receives IP multicasts directly from the sending device itself, ie it is NOT sent a copy via pseudo-multicasting from the WAP. I observe this by observing that the source MAC address of the MC packet is that of the sending device itself and NOT the MAC address of the Wifi Access Point. Both sender and receiver are connected to the same WAP.

So, if device A has MAC address macA, and WAP has MAC address macWap, a second device, subscribing to the MC address, receives MC messages with source MAC address macA and NOT macWap. Let's now say device A is connected to a WIFI network with SSID ssidA.

Let's also say that a second device, device B is in proximity to the WIFI network with ssidA, **but is actually connected** to a completely separate WIFI network named ssidB, supported by a completely different WAP device. As an example, device A is connected to my neighbour's WAP, device B is connected to my WAP, but device A and device B are just 10 metres from each other, ie easily within each others signal range.

The question then becomes, given device B appears to receive multicasts directly from device A itself (when both connected to the same SSID), will device B still see device A's multicasts, when transmitting device A is connected to ssidA and receiving device B is connected to ssidB. Basically is the multicast reception completely independent of the differing WIFI networks connected to by the 2 devices ???